# Django REST Framework: how to make Id field required upon POST, i.e. non read-only field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got a model, where I've overridden id as a CharField and primary key. Here's the model and its serializer:

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10000, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class ToolSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tool
        fields = (
            'id',
            'description',
            ...
        )
```

By default, Django REST Framework marks `id` field as read-only and doesn't require it upon POST requests. But I want it to be writable and require it upon POST. How do I achieve that?

Comment: just a curiosity, why would you need that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think, I found the answer in an unexpected place of DRF documentation:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update

I need to create an explicit `id` field in serializer like this:

```
class ToolSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Tool
        fields = (
            'id',
            'description',
            ...
        )
```

This will override the default id field, created as a read-only.

Comment: does it work? does it really update a pk field in the database?

Comment: Yes, it surely works for GET, POST and DELETE requests and I'm debugging PUT currently. I decided to do so because no tool names are unique and I can show their names to everyone (thus use tool names in urls). So why not use the names as primary ids? In that case, upon POST you have to specify the `id` for a tool, so I had to make `id` field non-read-only.

Comment: @KarinaKlinkevičiūtė just stumbled upon another reason for creating writable `id` field: implementing update on ListSerializers: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update